# Can Twitter Bootstrap alerts fade in as well as out?

Tags: jquery, css, alerts, twitter-bootstrap

When I first saw the alerts in Bootstrap I thought they would behave like the modal window does, dropping down or fading in, and then fading out when closed. But it seems like they are always visible. I guess I could have them sit in a layer above my app and manage showing them but I was wondering if the functionality was built in?

thanks!

Edit, what I have so far:

```
<div id="saveAlert" class="alert-message success fade in" data-alert="alert" style="top:0">
  <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
  <p><strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this alert message.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 144, accepted):

I strongly disagree with most answers previously mentioned.

**Short answer:**

> Omit the "in" class and add it using jQuery to fade it in.

See this jsfiddle for an example that fades in alert after 3 seconds http://jsfiddle.net/QAz2U/3/

**Long answer:**

Although it is true bootstrap doesn't natively support fading in alerts, most answers here use the jQuery fade function, which uses JavaScript to animate (fade) the element. The big advantage of this is cross browser compatibility. The downside is performance (see also: [jQuery to call CSS3 fade animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858939/jquery-to-call-css3-fade-animation)).

Bootstrap uses CSS3 transitions, which have way better performance. Which is important for mobile devices:

**Bootstraps CSS to fade the alert:**

```
.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
  transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
}
.fade.in {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Why do I think this performance is so important? People using old browsers and hardware will potentially get a choppy transitions with jQuery.fade(). The same goes for old hardware with modern browsers. Using CSS3 transitions people using modern browsers will get a smooth animation even with older hardware, and people using older browsers that don't support CSS transitions will just instantly see the element pop in, which I think is a better user experience than choppy animations.

I came here looking for the same answer as the above: to fade in a bootstrap alert. After some digging in the code and CSS of Bootstrap the answer is rather straightforward. Don't add the "in" class to your alert. And add this using jQuery when you want to fade in your alert.

**HTML (notice there is NO *in* class!)**

```
<div id="myAlert" class="alert success fade" data-alert="alert">
  <!-- rest of alert code goes here -->
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function showAlert(){
  $("#myAlert").addClass("in")
}
```

Calling the function above function adds the "in" class and fades in the alert using CSS3 transitions :-)

Also see this jsfiddle for an example using a timeout (thanks John Lehmann!): http://jsfiddle.net/QAz2U/3/

Comment: Internet Explorer doesn't support the transition property and IE8 and below don't support opacity, you have to use the filter property.. so anyone wanting to use this approach, graceful degradation is advised.

Comment: Well, it does degrade gratefully. Namely by not fading in or out. If you really NEED the fading then the bootstrap approach is not for you. If it just adds some extra bling to your design and want a future/mobile proof website, do as I did: reward users with modern browsers with pretty animations, and omit these for those who don't.  Instead of giving them potentially choppy/laggy animations because they use outdated hardware/software.

Comment: I've posted an alternative answer below. While, I'm in agreement that this answer is best for performance, I think it pollutes the markup. It's not clear that the classes `fade` and `in` are associated. As seen in the markup `class="alert alert-success fade in"`. The `in` class looks like a completely independent class, like `alert` or `alert-success`. It would be better to use the class-name `faded-in` (and `fade` should be `faded`), the transition is temporary, but the class-name lives on.

Comment: To make this work in Bootstrap 4, use the `"show"` class instead of `"in"`

Answer (score 28):

The thing I use is this:

In your template an alert area

```
<div id="alert-area"></div>
```

Then an jQuery function for showing an alert

```
function newAlert (type, message) {
    $("#alert-area").append($("<div class='alert-message " + type + " fade in' data-alert><p> " + message + " </p></div>"));
    $(".alert-message").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow", function () { $(this).remove(); });
}
newAlert('success', 'Oh yeah!');
```

Answer (score 18):

You can fade-in a box using jquery. Use bootstraps built in 'hide' class to effectively set display:none on the div element:

```
<div id="saveAlert" class="alert alert-success hide" data-alert="alert" style="top:0">
            <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
            <p><strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this alert message.</p>
        </div>
```

and then use the fadeIn function in jquery, like so:

```
$("#saveAlert").fadeIn();
```

There are also specify a duration for the fadeIn function, e.g:
    $("#saveAlert").fadeIn(400);

Full details on using the fadeIn function can be found on the official jQuery documentation site: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Just a sidenote as well, if you arent using jquery, you can either add the 'hide' class to your own CSS file, or just add this to your div:

```
 <div style="display:none;" id="saveAlert">
```

Your div will then basically be set to hidden as default, and then jQuery will perform the fadeIn action, forcing the div to be displayed.

Comment: This doesn't fade the alert-message in for me, it just shows it.

Comment: This will no longer work as of Bootstrap 3 - see https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/6342 under Miscellaneous

Answer (score 9):

For 2.3 and above, just add:

`$(".alert").fadeOut(3000 );`

bootstrap:

```
<div class="alert success fade in" data-alert="alert" >
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a>
    // code 
</div>
```

Works in all browsers.

Comment: Elegant and simple, thanks. I like the fact that there is no need to write js. There is a way to change the fade behavoir, like make fading longer?

Answer (score 6):

Add `hide` class to `alert-message`. Then put the following code after your jQuery script import:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $(".alert-message").animate({ 'height':'toggle','opacity':'toggle'});
    window.setTimeout( function(){
        $(".alert-message").slideUp();
    }, 2500);
});
```

If you want handle multiple messages, this code will hide them in ascending order:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
   var hide_delay = 2500;  // starting timeout before first message is hidden
   var hide_next = 800;   // time in mS to wait before hiding next message
   $(".alert-message").slideDown().each( function(index,el) {
      window.setTimeout( function(){
         $(el).slideUp();  // hide the message
      }, hide_delay + hide_next*index);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

None of the current answers worked for me.  I'm using Bootstrap 3.

I liked what Rob Vermeer was doing and started from his response.

For a fade in and then fade out effect, I just used wrote the following function and used jQuery:

Html on my page to add the alert(s) to:

```
        <div class="alert-messages text-center">
        </div>
```

Javascript function to show and dismiss the alert.

```
function showAndDismissAlert(type, message) {
    var htmlAlert = '<div class="alert alert-' + type + '">' + message + '</div>';

    // Prepend so that alert is on top, could also append if we want new alerts to show below instead of on top.
    $(".alert-messages").prepend(htmlAlert);

    // Since we are prepending, take the first alert and tell it to fade in and then fade out.
    // Note: if we were appending, then should use last() instead of first()
    $(".alert-messages .alert").first().hide().fadeIn(200).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000, function () { $(this).remove(); });
}
```

Then, to show and dismiss the alert, just call the function like this:

```
    showAndDismissAlert('success', 'Saved Successfully!');
    showAndDismissAlert('danger', 'Error Encountered');
    showAndDismissAlert('info', 'Message Received');
```

As a side note, I styled the div.alert-messages fixed on top:

```
    <style>
    div.alert-messages {
        position: fixed;
        top: 50px;
        left: 25%;
        right: 25%;
        z-index: 7000;
    }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this way to close fading my Alert after 3 seconds. Hope it will be useful.

```
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('.alert').fadeTo("slow", 0.1, function(){
        $('.alert').alert('close')
    });     
    }, 3000)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't agree with the way that Bootstrap uses `fade in` (as seen in their documentation - http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/alerts/), and my suggestion is to avoid the class names `fade` and `in`, and to avoid that pattern in general (which is currently seen in the top-rated answer to this question).

(1) The semantics are wrong - transitions are temporary, but the class names live on. So why should we name our classes `fade` and `fade in`? It should be `faded` and `faded-in`, so that when developers read the markup, it's clear that those elements were `faded` or `faded-in`. The Bootstrap team has already done away with `hide` for `hidden`, why is `fade` any different?

(2) Using 2 classes `fade` and `in` for a single transition pollutes the class space. And, it's not clear that `fade` and `in` are associated with one another. The `in` class looks like a completely independent class, like `alert` and `alert-success`.

The best solution is to use `faded` when the element has been faded out, and to replace that class with `faded-in` when the element has been faded in.

### Alert Faded

So to answer the question. I think the alert markup, style, and logic should be written in the following manner. *Note: Feel free to replace the jQuery logic, if you're using vanilla javascript*.

HTML

```
<div id="saveAlert" class="alert alert-success">
  <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
  <p><strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this alert message.</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.faded {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

JQuery

```
$('#saveAlert .close').on('click', function () {

  $("#saveAlert")
    .addClass('faded');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, Yes. Use this simple file in your project: https://gist.github.com/3851727

First add you HTML like this:

```
<div id="messagebox" class="alert hide"></div>
```

and then use:

```
$("#messagebox").message({text: "Hello world!", type: "error"});
```

You can pass all bootstrap alert types such as `error`, `success` and `warning` to `type` property as options.

Answer (score 0):

This is very **important question** and I was struggling to get it done (show/hide) message by replacing current and add new message.

Below is working example:

```js
function showAndDismissAlert(type, message) {

  var htmlAlert = '<div class="alert alert-' + type + '">' + message + '</div>';
  $(".alert-messages").prepend(htmlAlert);
  $(".alert-messages .alert").hide().fadeIn(600).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });

}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="alert-messages"></div>

<div class="buttons">
  <button type="button" name="button" onclick="showAndDismissAlert('success', 'Saved Successfully!')">Button1</button>
  <button type="button" name="button" onclick="showAndDismissAlert('danger', 'Error Encountered')">Button2</button>
  <button type="button" name="button" onclick="showAndDismissAlert('info', 'Message Received')">Button3</button>
</div>
```

Hope it will help others!