# jQuery to call CSS3 fade animation?

Tags: jquery, css

The animations that I am using on my site (which is developed for iOS) has a simple fade in and fade out using jQ:

```
$('.loading').fadeOut();
```

The iPhone, however, is choppy while running these animations. CSS3 animations work much smoother however. How can I fade out the `div` using jQuery but using CSS3 animations instead of the jQ ones?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easier, but once faded out it doesn't "disappear", so the page doesn't reflow once the transition is complete. It's equivalent to jQuery's `fadeTo()`, not `fadeOut()`;

Fade out

```
$('selector').css({
  "opacity": 0,
  "pointer-events": "none"
});
```

Fade in

```
$('selector').css({
  "opacity": 1,
  "pointer-events": "auto"
})
```

Delaying execution with Timeout

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('selector').css({
    "opacity": 1,
    "pointer-events": "auto"
  })
},)
```

Delaying execution with .delay

```
  $('selector')
    .delay(2000)
    .queue(function() {
       $(this).css({
        "opacity": 1,
        "pointer-events": "auto"
      })
    });
```

But this is probably best done through the transition delay property in your css:

```
  -vendor-transition-delay: 2s;
```

Or in shorthand:

```
  -vendor-transition: opacity 200ms ease 2s;
```

Comment: Is it possible to put a delay on it, ex `$('.loading').delay(500).css({`?

Comment: You must use the queue as in Zontan's example, but I prefer using straight js timeouts i.e. `setTimeout(function(){$('selector').css()}, 500)`

Comment: Does the queue work like this, `$('.loading').css.queue(function(){?` Also, why do you prefer using basic js timeouts?

Comment: I don't like going overboard with the chaining. I updated the answer with more examples.

Comment: Thank you for the update. The use of this is to display a loading screen when the page loads AJAX content, and then every time the AJAX request is called again. I'm not sure why this is happening, but you can only reload the AJAX once for it to show the loading screen: jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/9q9vK

Comment: You should have started from here, attach the fadeOut to the Ajax callback instead of faking the dynamic load with delay. Here is a much more simple implementation http://jsfiddle.net/E2Srk/

Comment: I agree with that idea. I have a few more questions, if you could answer them in chat when you have time. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6726/discussion-between-charlie-and-duopixel

Answer (score 6):

create a class with the CSS animation and attach it when needed -

```
$(".loading").addClass("fadeout").delay(2000).queue(function() {
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
});
```

Comment: This isn't the best way to do it though. While it does fade out the div, nothing is clickable (or tappable) behind the div after the transition is complete: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/SXFnt/

Comment: @Charlie - good point, updated that after the animation it will hide the element

Comment: I understand why that would work, but it doesn't seem to http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/SXFnt/1/

Comment: That works perfectly. What about a fadein after the fadeout's been already done? It seems like that since it makes it display none after the first loading, and then I try to make it fade in (using `opacity:1` for `.fadein` instead of `.fadeout`), it doesn't. I assume this is because it needs to be displayed block THEN faded in?

Comment: z-index is probably the clicking issue