# Bootstrap: How to fade and then hide something using the default 'fade', 'hide', 'in' classes?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, show-hide

Bootstrap obviously makes use of the 'hide', 'fade' and 'in' classes for its transitions.

The problem I'm having is that using 'fade' and 'in' will change the opacity from 0 to 1.  The transition effect is perfect, but the content is still there taking up space on the page, even if you can't see it.  For example, if it's container has a border, there'll be a big white space before the border.

I want to make use of their exisiting CSS transitions by adding and removing the 'in' class, but I also want whatever element that's fading out, to be hidden, but only after the transition is over.  So basically, exactly what they do in the modal, but I don't know how they do it.

In my example below, adding or remove the hide means the div appears or disappears instantly, before the fade effect can happen.

[JS fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/FU6pQ/)

Example HTML:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Choose one:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <label class="radio inline">
            <input type="radio" name="color-radio" id="yellow-trigger" value="yellow" />Yellow Box</label>
        <label class="radio inline">
            <input type="radio" name="color-radio" id="red-trigger" value="red" />Red Box</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="yellow-box" class="hide fade">
    <p>I'm yellow</p>
</div>
<div id="red-box" class="hide fade">
    <p>I'm red</p>
</div>
```

Example JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#yellow-trigger').click(function () {
        $('#yellow-box').addClass('in').removeClass('hide');
        $('#red-box').addClass('hide').removeClass('in');
    });

    $('#red-trigger').click(function () {
        $('#red-box').addClass('in').removeClass('hide');
        $('#yellow-box').addClass('hide').removeClass('in');
    });
});
```

Comment: may be try a time out like http://stackoverflow.com/a/13257654/1596547 see also http://bootply.com/62589

Comment: I used timeout in the end, thanks.

Comment: You can do this [without Javascript or Jquery now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679567/using-css-for-a-fade-in-effect-on-page-load)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using CSS for a fade-in effect on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679567/using-css-for-a-fade-in-effect-on-page-load)

Answer (score 15):

Any reason not to just use jQuery for the fadeIn effect?  Below is some code to make the fade in effect with jQuery.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/FU6pQ/14/)

Removed "fade" class

```
<div id="yellow-box" class="hide">
<p>I'm yellow</p> </div>
```

Updated jQuery for fade in

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#yellow-trigger').click(function () {
      $('#red-box').hide();
      $('#yellow-box').fadeIn('slow');
  });

  $('#red-trigger').click(function () {
      $('#yellow-box').hide();
      $('#red-box').fadeIn('slow');     
  });

});
```

Comment: In modern browsers (as of... at least 2020), this is not the best way to achieve this. Pure CSS transitions, as in the answer @maarten-von-middelaar

Answer (score 8):

This is very old, but in case anyone else gets here, the answer is to use a single-shot handler for the synthetic event `bsTransitionEnd`.

example:

```
$(".alert").one('bsTransitionEnd',function() {
    $(this).addClass('hide');
});
window.setTimeout(function(){
    $(".alert").removeClass('in');
},1000);
```

Comment: Thank you for the example, @maarten-van-middelaar !